# How to customize the page header and the page number of classicthesis?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, classicthesis

I am using the [classicthesis](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/) package and would like to customize the **page headers** and the **page numbers**. Here is a test project that shows the problem.

```
\documentclass[dottedtoc, headinclude, footinclude=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{lipsum,kantlipsum} % Generates dummy text.

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{scrheadings} % <--- Affects the page header and page number in the footer.

\part{Liechtenstein}
\chapter{Liechtenstein}\kant[1-6]\clearpage

\part{Germany}
\chapter{Germany}\kant[1-3]\clearpage
\section{Bavaria}\kant[1-6]\clearpage
\section{Hesse}\kant[1-6]

\end{document}
```

When I add `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` the page number jumps to the header as shown in the screenshot. I want the page numbers to stay at the footer. Nevertheless, I want a page header that shows the current *chapter* respectively the *section*. Please compile my example to recognize that some chapters do not have sections. It would be best, when I could manually decide whether the *chapter* name should be displayed on all pages of the chapter or whether the *section* names should appear.

[image: Wrong page header]

This following screenshots show how a page looks like *with* or *without* `scrheadings` enabled.

[image: With or Without scrheadings]

**Desired layout:**

- Page number always in the footer.
- Chapter name or section name in the header.
- Total page numbers in the footer. (optional)
- Manual configuration whether chapter or section name is shown in the header. (optional)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**1. Redefining `scrheadings`**
The redefinition of `scrheading` is described in chapter 5 in the [KOMAscript-manual](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf).

Add the following three lines to your MWE:

```
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\rightmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
```

You manipulate `chapter`or `section`in the header by changing between `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` in the second line, *i.e*.

```
\ohead{\rightmark}  % section-names in the header
\ohead{\leftmark}   % chapter-names in the header
```

If you use the option `twoside` to the class, you can use the command

```
\ohead{\headmark}
```

and have `chapter` names in the left-side heading and section names in the right-side headings, *automagically*.

**Page number `x of y`**
To have page number as ‘6 of 10’, add the package [lastpage](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) and redefine the `cfoot` to:

```
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark{} of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

*NB!* If you want the same page numbering in the `part`- and `chapter`-sides, add the same commands to the optional argument of `\cfoot`, *i.e.*

```
\cfoot[\pagemark{} of \pageref{LastPage}]% for pagestyle `scrplain`
     {\pagemark{} of \pageref{LastPage}}% for pagestyle `scrheading`
```

**3. Section number in heading**
To remove the section (or chapter-) number from the heading, in `KOMAscript` you use the commands:

```
 \renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}
```

and

```
 \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work in `classicthesis` (the spaced smallcaps disappear). Instead, you have to use

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
```

**4. Complete MWE**
Your MWE with all your requirements implemented:

```
\documentclass[dottedtoc, headinclude, footinclude=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{lastpage,lipsum,kantlipsum} % Generates dummy text.


\pagestyle{scrheadings} % <--- Affects the page header 
                        % and page number in the footer.
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\rightmark}  % comment this line and uncomment the next
                    % to switch to `chapter name` in the heading
%\ohead{\leftmark}  % comment out to 

\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
    \cfoot[\pagemark{} of \pageref{LastPage}]% for pagestyle `scrplain`
     {\pagemark{} of \pageref{LastPage}}% for pagestyle `scrheading`

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
% Remove section number from heading

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\part{Liechtenstein}
\chapter{Liechtenstein}\kant[1-6]\clearpage

\part{Germany}
\chapter{Germany}\kant[1-3]\clearpage
\section{Bavaria}\kant[1-6]\clearpage
\section{Hesse}\kant[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful! I owe you a beer!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Remove section number from heading implemented.

Comment: Your solution works great. I did not receive any notification from SE why I missed your edit. Thank you once again! *(I removed my former comments)*

Comment: Hello @Sveinung, can you take a look to this question please? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447489/wrapping-heading-classic-thesis-template

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Sorry for no reply. I have not been online for some days.