# Get the page number to the bottom with classicthesis

Tags: header-footer

How can i get the pagenumber to the bottom center of the page with the `classicthesis` template? Currently, the page number is in the header.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also this question is very similar to [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70610/how-to-customize-the-page-header-and-the-page-number-of-classicthesis). Please take a look at it as the informatio

Answer (score 4):

`classicthesis` still uses the obsolete package `scrpage2`. Add the follwoing after loading package classicthesis, or after loading `classicthesis-config`.

```
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead[]{\headmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
```