# How to get the page number in the bottom for all pages using classicthesis

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis

I am formatting my thesis using the classicthesis configuration for scrreprt class; this format puts the page number in the bottom for chapter pages and on the top for other pages, you can see a chapter page here:

[image: Chapter page]

What I would like to do is to place the page number in the bottom left or bottom right depending on if it is an even or odd page, better shown in this picture:

[image: Other pages]

I found solutions for placing the page number in the bottom here [How to customize the page header and the page number of classicthesis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70610/how-to-customize-the-page-header-and-the-page-number-of-classicthesis?rq=1) and here [Get the page number to the bottom with classicthesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232693/get-the-page-number-to-the-bottom-with-classicthesis?noredirect=1&lq=1) but both solutions use this code `\cfoot[\pagemark{}]` wich puts the pagemark in the center.

Heres a MWE with the `\cfoot[\pagemark{}]` code:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % fix some latex issues see: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fixltx2e.pdf
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,%
                dottedtoc,spanish%
                ]{scrreprt}
\input{classicthesis-config}

\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead[]{\headmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{spanish} 

\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoubleemptypage
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{Ensayo de Tensión}
\newpage
\section{Metodología utilizada}
\newpage
\section{análisis de resultados}    
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with the following code. I have replaced `\cfoot` by `\rofoot` (for right, even) and `\lofoot` (for left, odd).

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % fix some latex issues see: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fixltx2e.pdf
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,
                dottedtoc,spanish%
                ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead[]{\headmark}
\rofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\lefoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom

\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoubleemptypage
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{Ensayo de Tensión}
\newpage
\section{Metodología utilizada}
\newpage
\section{análisis de resultados}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much i did not know those option. Please, would you tell me where can I read more about this?

Comment: @PaulLara: These are commands from the KOMA-script bundle. You can find more about them in 'Chapter 5: Adapting Page Headers and Footers with scrlayer-scrpage' of the KOMA-script manual (https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).