# Wrapping heading - Classic Thesis Template

Tags: header-footer, templates, thesis, classicthesis

I have a long heading and thus it goes out of the margin. How can I fix it? I'm using classic thesis template; the only command in which there is the word heading is:

```
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

[image]

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis?lang=en

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Either make the title shorter (I don't think you need the first two words, for example, and a few more are probably redundant) or use `\section[short version] {full title}`.

Comment: Hello @PhilipPirrip, I like a lot your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make the title shorter (I don't think you need the first two words, for example, and a few more are probably redundant) or use `\section[short version] {full title}`, like in
 `\section[Funzionamento del biosensore elettrochimico]{Principio di funzionamento generale del biosensore elettrochimico reconfigur...}`